# Use signalr to notify all clients except self

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

I use Signalr 2.2 to send notifications to javascript clients through Hubs. Clients make HTTP requests to my REST web api (c#) and the my server uses the Signlar Hub to push updates to clients.

I know there is a way to manage the clients that the notifications are sent to but at the moment I always use: ~clients.all~. I don't know how can I tell the Id's of each connection, where should I keep those Ids and how to use them?

I've seen in erlier posts that ~clients.Others~ can be used but that seems to be relating to an older api of Signalr

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will work-

```
Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).hello(message);
```

Comment: I don't have the Context class available, is it in a different namespace or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can store connection information in the static dictionary in your Hub class. Here is the sample code

```
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _connections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public void SayHello(string message)
        {
            Clients.Others.hello(message);
        }

        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
        {
            _connections.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, string.Empty);
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            string value;
            _connections.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId, out value);
            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
```

Comment: What is the Clients.Others property? I don't have that

Comment: Which version of Signalr you are using? Here is the guide to Hub API calls http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients

Comment: I thinn I use the newest, 2.2.. one more question is how can I tell after Http request which client made the reqeust? I understand how to get clients ids when creating connections, but later on how can I use them?

Comment: In your case you need to pass connectionId as input to your REST API call and then use it server side. You can access connection id using code like 
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });
});

Comment: Is there a way I can achieve the connection id without adding it to every request? That will cause alot of code changing. Is there a way to put it in cache or cookie and take it in my controllers?

Comment: Yes you can store connection id in cookie and access it on server side using `CookieHeaderValue clientId = Request.Headers.GetCookies("client-id").FirstOrDefault();`